# No write permissions in /var/www/html

Tags: oracle, apache, centos, rhel

I am trying to run GLPi application on my Oracle Linux 7.0 where is only root user.

I have installed Apache, PHP and MySQL. But when I run application with GLPi in `/var/www/html/glpi` on http://example.com/gpli/. I get this errors after selecting language and accepting terms of licence.

[image: Here you can see problem I am talking about]

*Here you can see problem I am talking about.*

I tried change user and group to apache with `chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/gpli` and grant *full* access with `chmod -R a+rwx /var/www/html/gpli`, but it doesn't help at all.

I think there is simple solution but I tried read some manuals and it doesn't help at all. Can you help me figure it out? Thank you.

**SOLUTION:**

Problem was with SELinux I don't know there is something like that. I had to disable enforcing in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`. After that everything was ok.

After disabling SELinux I run this commands:

```
chmod 755 files && chown apache /[PATH_TO_GLPI]/files
find /[PATH_TO_GLPI]/files -type d -exec chown apache {} \;
find /[PATH_TO_GLPI]/files -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 755 config && chown apache /[PATH_TO_GLPI]/config
```

Answer (score 0):

Does GPLI create its own user? If so, you will have to give wheel permissions to that user. You could also give every user read, write, and execute permissions. Also, I see that you gave permissions to an account called "apache". Apache doesn't always create its own user. If it were me, I would just give everyone all permissions so that GPLI could definitely access it.

Comment: I don't think GPLi create its own user. And even if does, I don't get to this point yet because I am stack at this one. I tried install Nette Framework and there is the same problem. It can't write to log file because of permissions.

Comment: have you tried giving everyone wheel (r w x) perms?

Comment: I think it's not problem with this specific app, its problem with apache setting or something.

Comment: try `chown -R apache:apache glpi/files`

Comment: I try this and nothing. Entire directory `/var/www/html` have this `user:group`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :`chmod 775 /var/www/html/gpli`